# how to display selected node values angular ivh tree view?

Tags: angularjs, treeview

I am new to angularjs and need to display tree view structure. I came to know angular-ivh-tree view has lot of configurable options with checkbox support and hence tried in my application. It's displaying the treeview with checkboxes. But it's not displaying the slected node information when i selected some node in treeview.

Please guide me to display the selected node label, value and children.

Below code used in controller:

```
 $scope.bag = [{
            label: 'Glasses',
            value: 'glasses',
            children: [{
                label: 'Top Hat',
                value: 'top_hat'
            }, {
                label: 'Curly Mustache',
                value: 'mustachio'
            }]
        }];
};
```

below code used in html view:

```
 <div data-ivh-treeview="bag"
data-ivh-treeview-use-checkboxes="true"
         data-ivh-treeview-filter="bagSearch"    
data-ivh-treeview-selected-attribute="isSelected"></div>

    <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="x in bag">
                {{ x.label + ', ' + x.value }}
             </li>
    </ul>
```

used angular ivh related link:

> https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview

But children and selected node information not displaying.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

In your bag you have a key called "*children*".

The default key value for children objects in the **ivh-treeview** is "*items*":

```
ivh-treeview-children-attribute="'items'"
```

Look at the [Options](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview#options) section:

IVH Treeview is pretty configurable. By default it expects your elements to have *label* and *children* properties for node display text and child nodes respectively (...)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have asked another question, id be great if you can help out there, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083564/ivh-tree-disable-node-for-selection,