# ivh tree - disable node for selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, treeview, jstree

I am new to ivh tree (https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview) and using this library. I want to disable to certain nodes for selection, based on user entitlement

for example i have tree like this

```
$scope.bag = [{
            label: 'Glasses',
            value: 'glasses',
            entitled: false,
            children: [{
                label: 'Top Hat',
                value: 'top_hat',
                entitled: true
            }, {
                label: 'Curly Mustache',
                value: 'mustachio',
                entitled: false
            }]
        }];
};
```

So based on variable entitled: [boolean], it should let user select or unselect. how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you'll need to put some logic into a custom node template. Here's a stripped down example where I've introduced a helper directive that just inspects the `node` scope value and disables its checkbox if needed.

http://jsbin.com/buqaxu/2/edit?html,js,output

```
app.directive('isCbEnabled', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if(scope.node.disabled) {
        element.find('input').attr('disabled', true);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

You'd could attach something like this to your the `ivh-treeview-checkbox` directive in your template. Note that `node` is a supported scope variable within templates.